# Mouse right click context menu behavior

Tags: kubuntu, mouse

question is, how to make that right click on Linux works like on windows?

I mean that on windows...

- 1st click - menu appears
- 2nd click - opened menu disappears and a new
  menu appears

On Linux

- 1st click - menu appears
- 2nd click - opened menu disappears and ... that's all

How to make that on Linux context menu shows on any right click?

I have kubuntu 18.04 installed.

Comment: maybe this is a behavior that is met with another Desktop Environement. Other then that ubuntu don't do things just to resemble windows. I mean I'm all for it when it's a good idea. but in this case you might not have unanimity on whether the second click opening another is the more intuitive of the two. modifying this behavior is probably possible. I don't know the degree of dificulty though.

Comment: it doesn't matter how good this idea. I'm windows user. I try to make my dev environment on Kubuntu. I heard that in Linux you can customize almost everything in that way as you like. so, I keep going to hope that with some tool I can change right-click behavior. If no, It's OK.

Comment: oh not to worry. In linux the word of rule, absolutely **is** that you **can** change everything. not to be mistaken with "people have already changed this thing for me". there is no "tool" (at least not for this specific thing). you'll have to edit system files. what I mean when I say "I don't know the degree of dificulty" is : it may be a theme file (which is super easy), or desktop environment files (much harder), or kernel source code (quite a bit harder). I've never attempted this so I don't know which of the three (or other) handles this behavior in linux.

Comment: since Zorin tries to emulate windows perhaps they noticed this little detail and already remedied it. you should at least try it in a liveCD.